# How to get 256 colors working in ncurses program

Tags: c, ncurses

I am trying to run Listing 3-5 in the book Programmer’s Guide to NCurses by Dan Gookin (page 41).

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#define NEW_COLOR 1
#define RED 0
#define GREEN 750
#define BLUE 750
int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    start_color();
    if (!can_change_color())
    addstr("This probably won't work, but anyway:\n");

    init_color(NEW_COLOR, RED, GREEN, BLUE);

    init_pair(1, NEW_COLOR, COLOR_BLACK);
    attrset(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("This is the new color %d.\n", NEW_COLOR);
    refresh();
    getch();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried compiling it with:

```
gcc -o Listing3-5color_me Listing3-5color_me.c -lncurses
```

and with

```
gcc -o Listing3-5color_me Listing3-5color_me.c -lncursesw
```

In both cases the program compiles and runs but it doesn't show the right color.
It displays the "normal" red that is part of the first 8 or first 16 colors.

I know that my terminal (konsole) on Ubuntu 16.04 can display the 256 colors because I have seen other C programs that 
do not use ncurses display the 256 colors.

How do I get my ncurses program to use the 256 colors?